# Need I set all thread schedule policy to SCHED_RR to raise an thread priority?

Tags: linux, multithreading, macos, posix, native

We are developing multi-media cross platform application using `pthread API`. We want to make the raise the `audio` thread priority to make it works well even when the CPU is high. There are some thing not easy to observer by testing, so I want to understand how it works first.

And I searched the google, there is a lot of example to set the thread schedule policy to `SCHED_RR` and than set the priority.

For example [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/conceptual/kernelprogramming/scheduler/scheduler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH211-TPXREF109) example code on Apple documentation.

```
int set_my_thread_priority(int priority) {
     struct sched_param sp;

     memset(&sp, 0, sizeof(struct sched_param));
     sp.sched_priority=priority;
     if (pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &sp)  == -1) {
         printf("Failed to change priority.\n");
         return -1;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

If I set the audio thread as `SCHED_RR`, then I assume there are two group threads, one is `SCHED_RR` and the other `SCHED_OTHER`, and priority only effect thread relative order inside the group.

I'm wondering how can it works or just doesn't work, if just one thread in an task /process is `SCHED_RR`, and other threads schedule policy is by default to be `SCHED_OTHER`.

So the question is do I need to set the task/all threads schedule policy to `SCHED_RR`?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine though I'd recommend SCHED_FIFO instead. There's no need to set all your app's threads to the same scheduling policy. The OS is perfectly capable of scheduling all the threads in the whole system anyway.

Of course, if the high priority thread can be blocked by one of your other threads (waiting for a semaphore, etc) then you'd have to start dealing with that too. Linux out of the box doesn't sort out priority inversion. For that you need to apply the PREMPT_RT Patch set.

Comment: Does that means SCHED_RR thread will preempt the SCHED_OTHER thread?